I am getting the issue clerk authentication
I am using the clerk for user authentication, the issue I am getting is... whenever I run the project its directly opening clerk's official login page but I want my project's custom login page to be opened. So please help me to fix this issue.
I have changed the clerk credential which I have used but still I am getting the same issue

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

with limited information provided, I assume that you are using Clerks' SignInComponent
If it is true than:
Instead use SignIn/SignUp hooks to create your own signIn/singUp component and use these components wherever you like.
You should have something like this in your component:
const { isLoaded, signIn, setActive } = useSignIn();

await signIn?.authenticateWithRedirect({
          redirectUrl: "/main",
          redirectUrlComplete: "/main",
          strategy: "oauth_oauth_google",
        });

if you want to use password alternatevely:
signIn?.create({
        identifier: someEmailValue,
        strategy: 'password',
        password: somePasswordValue,
      });

Hope this will help
